# Splitting the legend in multiple rows in ggplot. Guides not accepting group aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to split the legend of my plot into two rows. I used the below code and it does not split the legend into two rows. I searched in the forums and most of them suggested using the grouping in aesthetics for eg if the group by variable is fill then the same has to be passed in guides argument. I did that with the group and it doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
points<-c("80","60","40","20","all")` 
var1<-c(59,48,44,39,36)
var2<-c(91,88,81,78,69)
var3<-c(98,97,96,93,90)  
var4<-c(8,7.5,6,5,4)  
data<-data.frame(points,var1,var2,var3,var4)  
data2<-melt(data,key=points) 
x<-ggplot(data2,aes(x=points,y=value,group=variable))+
    geom_line(aes(linetype=variable))+geom_point()+
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c(5,6,3,1))  
x+guides(group=guide_legend(nrow=2))
```

Comment: do you mean two columns with two rows each? Not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You changed the legend for the `group` aesthetic, not the `linetype`. I believe there is no legend associated with `group`. In fact the `group` mapping in your `aes(...)` is redundant since you used `linetype`.

```
x + guides(linetype = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

[image]